# Can't access internet from Vagrant libvirt VM

Tags: vagrant, kvm, libvirt

So, I setup a Vagrant libvirt VM, but I can't access internet using it. I can reach google.com from the host but not from the guest.

```
/home/vagrant# ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (64.233.177.105) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3075ms
```

nslookup shows this:

```
/home/vagrant# nslookup www.google.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 64.233.177.104
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 64.233.177.106
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 64.233.177.103
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 64.233.177.147
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 64.233.177.99
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 64.233.177.105
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4002:805::2004
```

I tried with `nslookup www.google.com 8.8.8.8` as well, but it didn't do anything. Any idea how to resolve this? TIA.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue right now on libvirt provider. I have not updated my OS and yet my vagrant VM worked just two days ago. Now it can't seem to get a response from any internet address. It can resolve names, it can talk to the host, but no packets get returned from internet IPs. As if a route or firewall setting is missing somewhere. I've tried reinstalling vagrant packages to trigger their scripts.